# html5 date input not working with bootstrap3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

EDIT: when I load my page on local with no CSS files, the date picker works just fine. How do I doctor my css / bootstrap less files to get them to leave the date picker alone???

---

Im running this on up to date chrome desktop with some bootstrap styling thrown in. Chrome desktop supposedly has date picker support, and the chrome date picker input UI displaying, and the arrows are working, **however the drop down carrot that displays the calendar is really buggy** (doesnt always display). Some days it drops down, other days it doesnt. Any idea what could be going on? I've tried removing all of the bootstrap and other css, divs etc, till buggy. This is a backend part of the site, and as such it doesnt need cross browser support, and I'd rather not further pollute my javascript with more jquery...

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class=form-group><label>Created After</label>
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="created" style="color: #000000;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a datepicker for bootstrap: [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

I used it for a project I worked on, didn't cause any problems. Documentation is provided, if you're not using bower, you can just add the Javascript and CSS file to get it working.